# How to ensure latest version of iOS Simulator Version?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My app submission has been rejected by Apple three times now (three weeks total) because I am unable to reproduce a bug they say exists. Apple mentioned they tested using:

"iPad running iOS 6.1.3 and iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4"

When I check my iOS Simulator, the only versions available are 5.1 and 6.1. How can I update my iOS Simulator so that it has 6.1.3 and 6.1.4?

Comment: Never rely on the simulator for final testing. While the simulator may be great to start building your application, always test it on real devices before uploading it to the App Store. After all it is only a simulator.

Comment: I agree. Currently I only have access to an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3 and I am still unable to reproduce the bug observed by Apple. I am beginning to suspect that this may be more a user training issue than a technical bug. I'm going to make some changes to further "idiot-proof" the app and re-submit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads and check the box that says "Check for and install updates automatically"

There you can also see what other components are available for you to download.

Hope this helps!

Comment: At 2019, it's XCode -> Preferences -> Components -> Simulator tab (not Toolchains).

Answer (score 38):

I have Xcode version 8.2.1 and to update Simulator you go to:

XCode --> Preferences --> Components

The Simulators segment filter will be selected by default. Double-click the particular version you would like to install.

It still has the checkbox as well to:

*Check for and install simulator documentation updates automatically*

[image: Screenshot Here]